# How to create new pane and run command in that pane using TMUX

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux, terminal-multiplexer

I have this which is pretty close:

```
tmux new -d -s "$session_uuid"
tmux send-keys -t "${session_uuid}.0" "tsc -w"  ENTER
tmux send-keys -t "${session_uuid}.0" "nodemon" ENTER
tmux attach -t "$session_uuid"
```

First, I am not sure what the .0 is....is that the window id?

What I want to do is create two vertical panes side by side and run `tsc -w` in the left pane and `nodemon` in the right pane. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Targets are session:window.pane so with `session.0`, the `0` is the pane number, but you don't need it, since there is only one window in a new session anyway, just the session name will be enough (put a colon after it if you want to be sure tmux knows it is a session).

You need to use `split-window` to split the window into two panes, something like this:

```
tmux new -d -s "$session_uuid" "tsc -w"
tmux splitw -t "$session_uuid:" -dh "nodemon"
tmux attach -t "$session_uuid"
```

If you want to be able to quit the programs and return to the shell, use `send-keys` like in your example, note the `.1` in the second `send-keys` to target the second pane (at the time of the first one the window only has one pane so it isn't needed):

```
tmux new -d -s "$session_uuid"
tmux send -t"$session_uuid:" "tsc -w" Enter
tmux splitw -t "$session_uuid:" -dh
tmux send -t"$session_uuid:.1" "nodemon" Enter
tmux attach -t "$session_uuid"
```

If you just want to let tmux assign the session name, you can use `-P` to get the target.

```
S=$(tmux new -dP "tsc -w")
tmux splitw -t$S -dh "nodemon"
tmux attach -t$S
```